# SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0 In fetch

Tags: javascript

```js
const say= document.querySelector(".quotes");

fetch(`http://quotes.rest/qod.js?category=inspire`)
 .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
})
 .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```

console error

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0
>   Promise.then (async)
>   (anonymous) @ quotes.js:8

[image]

I want to bring the price and print it out.

Comment: That looks like a JSONP response. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 2):

try to add a content-type and accept to the headers

```
const say= document.querySelector(".quotes");


fetch(`http://quotes.rest/qod.js?category=inspire`, {
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
})
 .then(function(response) {
     return response.json();
})
 .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I fixed the typo, but running it here results in a CORS issue.

Comment: Not long after I learned, I missed many options. Thanks for letting me know.
:)

Answer (score 1):

This endpoint is not returning application/JSON, it is returning application/javascript. This looks like its probably used as a part of a JSONP request because it is returning javascript that when executed continues the call chain.

In order to interact with the endpoint you need to either have a library that supports JSONP such as jquery or implement the support yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://quotes.rest/qod?category=inspire'
I missed this option.
thx :) for ur comment